# How to implement Material Design animation on my existing layouts

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, user-feedback

I know this is not the place for third-party libraries advertising, so I'll ask this on a as-generic-as-possible level: how can I implement material design onClick animation (the expanding circle) on my layouts? Is there something built-in or somebody-else-build-it in order to achieve this without writing my own animations from scratch?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is your question how to add that design functionality for the devices that can support it? If it is, you'll have to create api level specific layouts that use those new properties.

Comment: Hello Evan, thank you for answering. Do you mean that I can set up specific properties in my styles file for lollipop and get the animations on layouts for free on lollipop devices?

Comment: Absolutely. Check out this page: http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Comment: I think this would be a good place to start: https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

Comment: Thank you to both! I was more precisely referring to https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html. Didn't know it was enough (for post-lollipop devices) to apply standard tags in XML. Thank you!

Comment: For Everybody's Information: what I get from the various links is that implementing Ripples (and other animations) in Lollipop is pretty straightforward but it's discouraged on pre-lollipop versions because of the missing transaction libraries.